# Automatic email sending from a gmail account using script

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtp

I need to send email with same content to 1 million users.
Is there any way to do so by writing script or something?
Email Id's are stored in Excel format.

Comment: What do you mean by *10 lac different users*?

Comment: means i have an excel file which has email ids of 10lakh different users and i have to send them  same message.

Comment: There are many services for mailing, such as MailChimp, SendGrid, CampaignMonitor, and others. Unless you provide details of your approach of your python script, your goal itself with no further details could be interpreted as spam threat.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible for a bot to be made that creates gmail accounts, in fact many already exist. The main problem is how to solve the captcha that is required for each new account, however there are services already built to handle this. The only problem then is being willing to violate googles terms of services, as I'm sure this does in one way or another.

Comment: no i don't have to create any account . i have an excel file which has the email id column and message column,i just want to use that data to automate the process of mailing this message to their email id's

Comment: also same scenario in mail sending

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you to achieve what you wanted

http://naelshiab.com/tutorial-send-email-python/